# AWS SES - 554 Message rejected

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

My application uses SES to send Emails. Application is throwing below exception while trying to send emails. But, the email Id is verified successfully in SES and I'm able to send Test email from this Id successfully from AWS console.

```
Exception: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: MyApp@mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, make sure to use the exact email id **including the case** that you have configured in AWS SES.

Eg: if you have verified the email `myapp@mydomain.com` then don't use `MyApp@mydomain.com`.